# JS/CSS Currency formatting - ISO Code left, Value to the right

Tags: css, currency-formatting

I am receiving currency as a string from an API, and it looks like this : "USD 10,000.00", I can have "USD 10.00" etc.. What I want to accomplish is to align the currency ISO code to the left of my table, and the value to the right - not the column right, but the longest string right, as shown in the example below.

Image of the desired solution
[image]

The table flexes so that all columns are the same size, and that is why I need this functionality. My thoughts for now are that the total sum will always be the widest element and we need to get it's width, but since my framework restricts onload() methods, I can't wait for the total element to render, thus giving me 0 for offsetWidth when I load the table for the first time. Any ideas, thoughts?

Comment: you're using a `<table>` ? Could you provide the HTML where this would be embed ?

Comment: I am using a table. This needs to be working in a <td> element. I would post html, but primarily what it is is <td> functionality here </td>. Nothing more.

Comment: do you know if the currency will always be in front of the value ? (usually we write 5.00 € and not € 5.00). If so, you can split on the space character to get the two parts

Comment: The currency will always be in that format and '-' when it's empty. The format is 'ISO $XXX".

Comment: something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/2ergrokr/2/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle @ValLeNain. It should be like that. The problem that occurs for me is that the column can be wider than the USD 10,000 value, and that way I can't really use right float or text align right. Also, all this is happening in a <td> , and it's a part of a much bigger table.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the formatted currency into two parts with a regex, and then use two columns to display the formatted amount, with text in the currency code column left justified, and text in the numbers column right justified.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried that, and that'd work if I knew the width of the column or of the longest string/formatted value. The problem is, on render I cant know the width of the longest value, because it might be 0. I don't want to use the width of the column for right alignment/justifying, I want to use the longest value in the column, as in the photo.

Comment: Can't you set up the width of the table column to be automatic, so it automatically resizes to be just big enough to display the longest value?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That's the easy solution, but UI team doesn't like it.

Comment: You said you can't wait for the total element to render, but can you get the total value and format it before anything has rendered, so that you know the target width you want to size everything else to match?

Comment: I want the width of the container of the values to be adapted to the width of the total element whenever it loads (or is rerendered when it changes).

Comment: Then it seems very strange to me that your UI team doesn't like the idea of a table column resizing itself, because it sounds like no matter what you do, you'll have dynamic column resizing going on.